Count number of 'matches' between two dataframes with same column
I have two dataframes:
head(Dataframe One):
    A tibble: 6 × 3 
Groups:   Site [1]
  Site  Species                  n
  <chr> <chr>                <int>
1 BRY1  American Goldfinch       5
2 BRY1  Brown-headed Cowbird     1
3 BRY1  Carolina Wren            1
4 BRY1  Chimney Swift            4
5 BRY1  Common Nighthawk         2
6 BRY1  Common Yellowthroat      1

head(Dataframe Two):
# A tibble: 6 × 3
# Groups:   Site [1]
  Site  Species               n
  <chr> <chr>             <int>
1 BRY1  Chimney Swift         1
2 BRY1  Gray Catbird          1
3 BRY1  House Wren            1
4 BRY1  Indigo Bunting        1
5 BRY1  Northern Cardinal     1
6 BRY1  Warbling Vireo        1

I would like to find the number of Species 'matches' between these two dataframes by site. Both dataframes have Species data for 9 sites (BRY1 - BRY9; different number of rows for each site), and I would like a count of how many species 'match' for each site between the two dataframes. More simply, if both dataframes have an entry for Chimney Swift in site BRY1, that would be 1 'match'.
I have been trying to use the semi_join() function, with limited success.
I appreciate your time and support!

It's easier to help you if you include a simple reproducible example with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Share the output of dput() rather than head(). What did your attempts with semi_join() look like and how exactly was it off?

inner_join(df1 |> ungroup(), df2 |> ungroup(), join_by(Site, Species)) |> count(Site)?

You nailed it, Jon Spring. Thank you!

matched_species <- Data frame One %>%
semi_join(Data frame Two, by = c("Site", "Species")) %>%
count(Site)
matched_species

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
